# What does 'In [*]' mean in Jupyter notebooks?

Tags: jupyter-notebook

What does `In [*]` at the upper left-hand of the cell mean when running a Jupyter notebook?

I know that when the cell in Jupyter notebook has not been run, it shows as `In[ ]`, after running the cell, it shows as `In[num]`.

What about `In [*]`, does it mean that this cell is running now?

[image: screenshot]

Comment: it means: `currently evaluating`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What does In \[\*\] in IPython Notebook mean and how to turn it off?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30421373/what-does-in-in-ipython-notebook-mean-and-how-to-turn-it-off)

Comment: Yes, the kernel is busy. If this persist, you can [turn if off](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30421373/what-does-in-in-ipython-notebook-mean-and-how-to-turn-it-off?rq=1).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Jupyter notebook not running code. Stuck on In \[\*\]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46383177/jupyter-notebook-not-running-code-stuck-on-in)

Answer (score 30):

This means that your kernel is busy. 
If you want to interrupt/stop the execution, go to the menu Kernel and click Interrupt.If it doesn't work, click Restart. 
You need to go in a new cell and press Shift + Enter to see if it worked.

Comment: Can I know progress (in percent about the kernel procesing) ?

Comment: No, you can not. You could, however, implement a progress bar within you cell's code.

Answer (score 6):

When a cell is displayed as "busy" with an asterisk, it can mean one of several things:

- The cell is currently executing.
- An "execute" command was sent to the cell, but another cell is currently executing. The cell will execute when its turn comes.
- The kernel was interrupted / restarted while the cell was executing, it is currently not executing.

Answer (score 0):

When a cell is displayed with an asterisk it means it's busy.
It might mean that: 1) The cell is now executing; 2)or it will execute when it's turn arrives. 3)or it is not executing because the kernel was restarted or interrupted.

My recommendation is that you save the file and restart the kernell in preferrence without running everything, but if you are sure everything can run without problems just do it and it will be faster for you.

Answer (score -1):

it would mean that either your code timed out or ran out of memory,
Check for infinite loops or memory leaks.