# Jupyter notebook not running code. Stuck on In [*] until interrupted and run again

Tags: jupyter-notebook, kernel, jupyter, interrupt, reinstall

I have an issue with running the blocks on Jupyter notebook, without interrupting them first.

I run the code it shows that it is  Stuck on In [*],
But, if I interrupt the kernel and run it again it works. This happens every single time in every single code.

I have tried the solutions in this link as well [Jupyter notebook not running code. Stuck on In [*]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46383177/jupyter-notebook-not-running-code-stuck-on-in)[image: stuck in [*] until interrupted and run again]

Comment: Can you post the other cells as well so we can get a better idea of what might be going on?

Comment: Hi, I am not running any other cell. I just run this one cell, it runs forever, I interrupt the kernel and run again and it prints the output

Comment: Your "kc_sales_2019q1" dataframe has to be being built somewhere. Where is that?

Answer (score 0):

This happens when the same program running again and again then it goes to an infinite loop in a kernel or generally it because of the fault of the threaded system, if put 4 to 5 calls concurrently then it goes to stuck situation. It can be solved just go through the **dashboard** bar of jupyter on topmost here u find **kernel** click on that and then from there click on **interrupt**. Then problem resolved.

Comment: In my case, the problem is resolved but then start again. Any advice on this continuous problem?