# I am trying to send an email to myself through python using smtplib, but it's not running

Tags: python

I am working in Jupyter Notebook using Python 2 and when I try to connect to smtplib.SMTP("smtp.gmail.com", 587) the code won't stop executing...

I've already tried to let less secure apps into google as I saw some people do in some solutions.

```
import smtplib

server = smtplib.SMTP("smtp.gmail.com", 587)
server.ehlo()
server.starttls()

from getpass import getpass
username = "myemail"
password = getpass()
```

I get the In [*] problem indicating that the kernel is still trying to execute this. However, when I looked up the tutorial online, it worked wonders for them.

Comment: Check this for the ln[*] problem [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30421373/what-does-in-in-ipython-notebook-mean-and-how-to-turn-it-off)

Comment: I tried to do this, however it still is giving me the same error. I think it has to do with the smtplib.SMTP("smtp.gmail.com", 587) isn't responding...