# What does it mean when a Jupyter cell has an asterisk?

Tags: python-3.x, jupyter

[image]

I have python code that works, because I'm also testing it in a Udacity workspace.  However, it's not working in Jupyter.  I've noticed an asterisk next to the cell.  What does this mean, and how do I resolve it?

I do not believe the kernel is busy, because I can still individually run other cells.  It's only the cells with Print statements that seem to be affected.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What does In \[\*\] in IPython Notebook mean and how to turn it off?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30421373/what-does-in-in-ipython-notebook-mean-and-how-to-turn-it-off)

Comment: @buræquete  I looked at those answers, but they don't help.  Other cells run just fine.  It's only the ones that have print statements.  They "appear" to run, but they don't produce any output.

And Thank you for being aware of another possible question / answer so quickly.

Comment: "_they don't produce any output_": You seem to be `print`ing the result of functions `stringtest` and `until_dot`. If there is nothing printed, it means the function has not yet returned (is not yet finished) so there is no output yet.

Answer (score 0):

That means the cell is still running and the kernal is busy.  I'm not sure of the exact reason why your code is taking a long time to run without running through the code.

Answer (score 0):

Are you running multiple cells when this happens? If yes, try running cells one by one. That case is mentioned in an issue comment:
https://github.com/jupyter/notebook/issues/2216#issuecomment-295440115

The issue itself discusses the ambiguous meanings of the asterisk, and was closed without a resolution.

Answer (score -3):

Try this instead.
Its a compiling issue. Try selecting proper interpreter.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/35598036)